# probability that 5 square lie along a diagonal line

Tags: probability

If $5$ squares are chosen at random from a chess board, what is the probability that they lie on a diagonal line?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

HINT:

1. There are $64$ squares altogether; how many ways are there to choose $5$ of them?
2. There are $15$ diagonals in each direction, but only $7$ of them are long enough to contain $5$ squares. Specifically, in each direction there are two diagonals of length $5$, two of length $6$, two of length $7$, and one of length $8$. How many $5$-element subsets are there of each of these diagonals?

The total in (2) is the number of sets of $5$ squares that lie on a diagonal. The total in (1) is the total number of sets of $5$ squares. Combine these two numbers to get the desired probability.

Comment: Thanks Brain M. Scoot Got it.We can select $5$ square out of $64$ is $\displaystyle \binom{64}{5}$ now for favourable no. of cases  $ = 2.\left\{\binom{5}{5}+\binom{6}{5}+\binom{7}{5}\right\}+\binom{8}{5}$ This is for anong one diagonal $(AC)$ same things for another diagonal $(BD)$ So tatal is $ = 112+112 = 224$ So probability is $\displaystyle = \frac{224}{\binom{64}{5}}$

Comment: @juantheron: You’re welcome; looks good.

Answer (score -2):

There is $16$ possible arrangements of $5$ squares so that they are on the diagonal lines and $64*63*62*61*60$ possible ways to put squares on the chessboard so the probability is $16\over(64*63*62*61*60)$

Comment: While I suppose the denominator could be correct (taking the order in which squares are chosen as making a difference), there's no way the numerator 16 could be compatible with this way of counting.  Even one set of five squares in a diagonal would give rise to a count of at least 5! arrangements of those squares (according to the order chosen).

Comment: Well, it depends on whether you see $5$ chosen squares which are on the same position as one arrangement or $5!$ arrangements, i choose it to be one because they constitute the same location on the chessboard.

Comment: Then your enumeration of all subsets of 5 squares on the board (denominator) is also wrong.